# Vue Computed Component Not Firing

Tags: vue.js

I've been running the Vue extension for Chrome. As soon as I turned it off, none of my computed components work. All of my data comes from Django. One example:

```
import axios from 'axios'
    

export default { 
    name: 'Game',
    
    data() { 
        return { 
            game: {},
            newDate: ''
        }
    },

    computed: {
        dateNoTime() { 
                    this.newDate = this.game.date.substring(0, this.game.date.indexOf("T"));
        }
```

If I have the Vue extension loaded, using {{ newDate }} works just fine. Without it, however, nothing gets pulled. I've tried a method as well with no luck.

Comment: `this.game.date` is undefined, substring will only work on strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one worked when I tested it

```
methods: {
  dateNoTime: function () { 
    this.newDate = this.game.date.toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'/');
  }
},
  mounted () {
  this.dateNoTime()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have no doubt this is the correct answer. Unfortunately there is obviously something I'm doing wrong with collecting my data from Django. It seems it doesn't exist when I'm calling {{ newDate }}. Just confused why it works with the chrome Vue extension.
Waaay back to the basics I think. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all computed property has to return some value.
Please refer to official Vue documentation.
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example

Comment: return this.game.date.substring(0, this.game.date.indexOf("T")); 
does not work.

Comment: How are you using the dateNoTime value? 
It seems the this.game.data does not exist at the moment.

Comment: Just calling the variable {{ newDate }}
Something off with the way I'm getting my data from Django I suppose. Frustrating that everything worked like a charm with the Vue Chrome extension on. Going back to basics. Thanks for the help.